# Starting Game dev on iPhone:iPad - learning path?

Tags: iphone, ipad, sdk

I'm beginning in iPhone/iPad game dev and I'm searching to set up my learning path.
The basic features I would like to learn (after the basic SDK iphone components programming) are :

- using a board like interface where I can move pawn with my fingers
- detect where the pawn was moved and triggers events in the game
- The board will be constitute by 6 tiles that may be organised randomly when starting the game : may i use an sdk component with a delegate and datasource to determine where the pawn was left and on which tile ?
- need to use dices (which kind of library may I use ?)
- ...

Do you have any idea about where to start ? ;-)

Many thanks,
Tib.

Comment: I think there are numerous books on iPhone game dev, you should get one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jens Alfke has provided the [GeekGameBoard](http://bitbucket.org/snej/geekgameboard) framework for building Mac or iPhone board and card games.  He talks about it [here](http://jens.mooseyard.com/2008/03/geekgameboard-getting-closer-to-iphone-ready/).  I'd highly recommend that as a starting point for an inexperienced developer looking to create a board game.

Additionally, you might look at the answers to the similar question ["iPhone board game: OpenGL ES or CoreGraphics?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082511/iphone-board-game-opengl-es-or-coregraphics).  As I recommend there, read up on Core Animation (what GeekGameBoard uses for layout and animation) for providing your layered graphics and animation, rather than jumping straight into the more complex OpenGL ES.

Comment: ok great, is the GeekGameBoard importable as iPhone / iPad project ...
I'll try this tonight.
thanks a lot.

Following your answer (thanks for it) I understand that it is more efficient to go to OpenGL/CoreGraphics than using a framework like Cocos2D ? 
I guess it is better to learn the basics before using a framework, Am I right ?

Comment: @Tibi - GeekGameBoard works on the iPhone OS, so you can use it within your iPhone / iPad project.  There's a specific iPhone project for building it for that platform.  My suggestion in that question was to go with Core Animation (Core Graphics is not used for animation, just 2-D drawing that you would use within Core Animation) over OpenGL ES due to how much simpler it will be to write your application.  Cocos2D is layered on OpenGL ES, but I haven't used it so I can't comment on how difficult it would be to work with.

Comment: hello again, 
would this book be a good starting point to learn about 2D Core Animation with some openGL introduction ?

Comment: @Tibi - I haven't read that one myself, but I can speak for this book as an excellent reference to Core Animation: http://www.amazon.com/Core-Animation-Simplified-Techniques-Development/dp/0321617754/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1272027719&sr=8-1 and this one as a technical reference for OpenGL ES: http://www.amazon.com/Mobile-3D-Graphics-Kaufmann-Computer/dp/0123737273/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1272027753&sr=1-1 .

Comment: @Tibi - You might also be interested in the course notes for my iPhone development class (VoodooPad format): http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/AdvancediPhoneApps.zip, where I cover all of these topics.  The class itself will be out on iTunes U for free in a few months.

Comment: @Brad Larson - the book looks interesting indeed, I'll try to find it. Many thanks. I'll check your dev class tonight. thanks a lot.

Comment: Concerning GeekGameBoard as provided by Jens Alfke. May it be used in a personal project ... or even on a commercial project ?? which kind of license is there on that "framework"

Comment: @Tibi - It is BSD licensed, so it is perfectly fine to use within your own closed-source application (with proper attribution, if necessary).